# Subclassing UITextfield in Swift to recognise delete/backspace key

Tags: ios, swift

Hey I'm trying to subclass UITextField in Swift so I can detect when the delete/backspace key is pressed. So far I have this:

```
import UIKit

class DigitTextField: UITextField {

    var delegate: digitFieldDelegate?


    func deleteBackward() {
        super.deleteBackward()
        delegate?.backspacePressed()

    }

}

protocol digitFieldDelegate {

    func backspacePressed()

}
```

Now I have changed the UITextField class to DigitTextField in the IB and created the connections in the viewController. I am getting the error *use of undeclared type DigitTextField*. What am I doing wrong here? Any pointers would be really appreciated. thanks

Comment: Implement [UITextFieldDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/)

Comment: You can't override the default delegate of UITextField which type UITextFieldDelegate. If you want to create your own protocol, change delegate to other name.

Comment: @Adam where? In my subclass file?

Answer (score 0):

As LE SANG pointed out in the comments, you cannot just write your own `delegate` property to override the old one. It just doesn't work!

What you have to do is to change your property's name to something else, so that the names will not clash and the old text field delegate can still do what it should do.

Just like this:

```
var myDelegate: digitFieldDelegate?
```

And of course you should also change the word in the `deleteBackwards` method!

Also it is recommended to use PascalCase to name protocols:

```
protocol DigitFieldDelegate {
    //...
}
```